# How to add a fixed range vertical line to a D3.js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add a vertical line on an existing line chart. My data looks likes this - column PC is a calculated percentage - and the vertical line should extend from 0 to 100 percent on the chart:

```
var data = [
{"Month":"2014-06" , "PC" : 38 , "items" : 72 }, 
{"Month":"2014-07" , "PC" : 33 , "items" : 68 }, 
{"Month":"2014-08" , "PC" : 28 , "items" : 80 }, 
{"Month":"2014-09" , "PC" : 16 , "items" : 93 }
]
```

I build the y axis fine as follows where I have forced the range to be 0 to 100, since the data values do not actually cover the full range:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0], 0.5);
y.domain([0, 100]);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; }).ticks(10);
```

To create the vertical line, I try this:

```
 var linev = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { 
      return x(data[2].Month); })
.y(function(d, i) { return y(i); }); 

 svgx.append("path")
      .datum(data)
    .style("fill", "none")
     .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .attr("d", linev);
}
```

The line forms, but I cannot get it to extend in the same range from 0 to 100 percent that the axis does, as I fail to get this line right:

> .y(function(d, i) { return y(i); });

How do I make that set of y values cover the y value of all all the points on the chart corresponding to the percentages from 0 to 100?

Comment: Use `y(d.PC)`. `i` is the index of the item in the dataset, so probably not what you want here.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had tried that. That does produce a vertical line, but it extends from 0 to 38% for the data I have given above, since 38 is the largest PC value. I would like to have the line extend to 100, which is the forced high value (ie there is no such actual value in the data) for the 0% to 100% range.

Comment: Add 100 to the data set at the appropriate position.

Comment: Hmmm. If I add a point to the dataset with value of 100, that would add a false point to the actual line graph as far as I can see. Unless I filter it out, but that seems messy. I suppose, though, that I could create a separate dataset and base the vertical line y off that data. But it seems like there ought to be an easier or more direct way.

Comment: If I add a second, dummy dataset in order to extend the range to 100, I am also not sure how I would reference it, given that 'd' points to the actual dataset.

Comment: Well, I could add another column to the existing dataset that would scope the range 0 to 100. That will do it. Is there no more direct way?

Comment: It's not clear at all to me what you're trying to achieve. Why/how to you want to cover the entire range? Don't you want to plot just the data you have?

Comment: It is an animated line chart with the animation across the months. There is actually a dataset for each month (not shown). So at June, 2014, 38% of items developed in June have been shared. By July, 42% of the June items have been shared. The vertical line is simply a line that moves across the chart during the animation showing the current month of the animation while the curve of the line chart changes month to month. So this vertical line simply extends across the chart from bottom to top - a guide line.

Comment: So for that you would do a completely separate line, no? Something like `svg.append("line").attr("y1", y(0)).attr("y2", y(100)).attr("x1", ...).attr("x2", ...)`.

Comment: Yes, that does it - many thanks, Lars!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by appending a separate line that has the appropriate `y` coordinates:

```
svg.append("line")
   .attr("y1", y(0))
   .attr("y2", y(100))
   .attr("x1", ...)
   .attr("x2", ...)
```

where the coordinates for `x1` and `x2` are the same and determine the position of the vertical line.

Comment: Quick note in passing: don't forget to give some thickness to the line to make it visible, e.g.:  `.attr( "stroke", "black" ).attr( "stroke-width", "2" );`