# ClojureScript NVD3 full-height shaded intervals

Tags: d3.js, svg, nvd3.js, clojurescript, om

My graphs currently indicate "no data" by calculating the holes in my datasets, then generating a new fake dataset that ranges from `nil` to `max(all-y-values)`, thus making it look like a full-height background. I make it an "area" dataset and apply an SVG pattern to make it look like this:

[image: calculated shaded intervals]

The problem arises when the y-axis scale is greater than the data, in other words when `max(all-y-values)` doesn't coincide with the top of the graph.

I need to make these shaded background intervals **always the full height of the graph**, and I'm willing to rethink the whole process of adding them.

My recent attempts have been trying to follow the "filling an area above the line" example described in [D3 Tips and Tricks](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-filling-an-area-above-the-line) as well as the [NVD3 documentation](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#line) and [various](http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/setting-scales-domains-and-ranges-in.html) other [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274602/823470), but I haven't seen anything working.

This is the "filling an area above the line" example from that link:

[image: "filling an area above the line" from D3 Tips and Tricks]

Any solution must either use ClojureScript and Om or at least be directly compatible with them, since I already have a proof of concept in the above links and I am looking for more.